# Jquery add image, no click event

Tags: jquery, live

I'm appending a table row with an image that when you click it, it fires an event.  However it looks like you can't add a 'clickable' image dynamically.

all the previous rows with images are identified by their class attribute when clicked (they loaded with the page).

What I want to avoid is using the live event and making a seperate function, I just want it to click like all the others :(

So the question is, how do I add an event that just makes the existing (already being used) function identify the class of the dynamically added image when clicked...?

---

Thanks for your help, but I am completely clueless about jquery and named functions

In the end I created a live event and copied the code from the original function. If anybody knows how I can call one function from both processes it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a named function you want to apply when adding new images:

```
function doSomeMagicThing() { //handle image }
```

You can wrap your `img` html, like:

```
//work now on $newImage, which is a jquery element containing your new image.
var $newImage = $('<img src="some_path.png" />');

//Remember it is not yet in your page, so you will have to 
//append it when you are done working with it.
$newImage
    .click(doSomeMagicThing);                        //add click event
    .appendTo($('someSelectorWhereToAppendTo'));     //append it somewhere!
```

Comment: it's not a named function it's a  $(".class").click(function()

how do you make a named function in jquery?

Comment: You don't make it "in jquery". Javascript functions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can make a named function as in any JavaScript:

```
function myFunc(){

}
```

In your jQuery code you can then use `.click(myFunc)`. The function `myFunc` is being passed as a 'callback'. In your old code you have been passing an anonymous function as a callback in the same way, assuming you did something like `.click(function(){   })`.

A common pitfall is to write accidentally `.click(myFunc())`, which passes the *return value* of `myFunc` as the callback instead of `myFunc` itself.

You can treat functions as variables for most purposes (they have 'scope' in a similar way, except functions can't be redefined later). You can even create named functions by assigning anonymous ones to variables:

```
var myFunc = function(){

}
```

and then you can treat `myFunc` exactly as you would any other variable.